# how to get the value attribute of a drop down list <option> and use it in php code

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, get

I have a drop down list which is dynamically populated from a MySQL database :

```
<select name= "studentnames" >
<option value="0">Select a Student</option>

$RSStudentName = mysql_query( "SELECT StudentName, StudentID FROM Students " );

while($StudentNameList = mysql_fetch_object($RStudentName))
    {
    <option value = "<?php echo $StudentNameList->StudentID ;?> " >

    <?php 
        echo $StudentNameList->StudentName ;
     ?>
    </option>       
<?php 
    }
?>
</select>
```

---

The drop down gets filled these items as below :

**Student1**

**Student2**

**Student3**

**Student4**

---

Student Table is as :

> ### SID  |   SNAME
>
> S001 |   Student1
>
> S002 |    Student2
>
> S003 |   Student3

Now when the users selects a student name from the drop down list, i want to get the value of that option , and insert it into a table. How to do this?

That is, if user selects `Student3` in the drop down list, then i want to get `S003` in some variable and insert it in a table? Please help with how to get the value attribute in a variable.

Could this be done?

```
$sid = $_POST('studentnames').value;
```

Comment: Are they submitting a form?  Or right when someone chooses a student it should do an insert?  What if they accidentally select the wrong student and change it again?

Comment: You are overwriting your resultset. Use different variable names (e.g. `$result` for the resultset).

Comment: Yes , on form submit, i would insert the value.......

Comment: You dont have an insert transaction on the page? I' confused by your question, what table do you want to insert the data into?

Comment: @Liam : I just want to know, HOW TO GET THE VALUE ATTRIBUTE of the selected item in the drop down?

Comment: @ThiefMaster : i have edited my post, please check it again

Comment: @Aaron W. : sir, please have a look once more , i have changed the last lines........

Comment: @sqlchild: No caps please. If you want to emphasize something surround it with `*` or `**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simpel form post: the selected value will be in:

```
$_POST['studentnames']
```

In your code, use the ID as VALUE, and the name just as text

```
<option value="[id field]">[studentname]</option>
```

then

```
$_POST['studentnames']
```

will contain the is, might be better then naming it simply 'student'...

Comment: sir, but this would give me the StudentName, but i want to Get the STUDENTID ? like it user selected Student3, then i want to get its corresponding ID , S003, in some variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag should have a method="post" attribute. Then you can access the data using:

```
$value = $_POST['studentnames'];
```

Remember that accepting raw $_POST data opens your project up to various injection security issues. Make sure you clean and validate the data before it goes anywhere near the database or is displayed back to the user.

Comment: sir, but this would give me the StudentName, but i want to Get the STUDENTID ? like it user selected Student3, then i want to get its corresponding ID , S003, in some variable?

Comment: It should give you the ID. Have you checked the source of the HTML to see if the select element is correctly structured with the options? It will only give you the StudentName if the option values are not present or incorrectly formatted.

Comment: ok sir, thanks a lot, also,  if i want to get the text which is displayed in the drop down , then what would i have to do??????? like, if user selects Student3, then how do i get Student3 in some variable???????

Comment: ok sir, thanks a lot, also, if i want to get the text which is displayed in the drop down , then what would i have to do??????? like, if user selects Student3, then how do i get 'Student3' in some variable???????

Comment: Unless you leave out the value parameter, the only way to actually get the option content is to use javascript.

Comment: also , how do i put that in a variable to use it in php code?

Answer (score 0):

Post it with a form, and get the value like this:

```
<?php

$somevariable = $_POST["studentnames"];

?>
```

Comment: if i want to get the text which is displayed in the drop down , then what would i have to do??????? like, if user selects Student3, then how do i get 'Student3' in some variable??????? –

Comment: Get it from the database: $query = mysql_query("SELECT StudentName FROM Students WHERE StudentID = ".intval($studentid)); $studentName = mysql_result($query,0);

Answer (score 0):

```
$Getname = $_POST['studentnames'];
```

This gets the value of what the user selects

then sql should get like

$query = "INSERT INTO Members (studentnames)VALUES('$Getname')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

That SQL will add the $Getname on to the Members table